# How come css changes a div when I add a block-styled element inside it?

Tags: html, css

When I remove the display:block from a p inside a div, it ignores the top-margin or it's own hight or something like that. It snuggles up right next to the element above it. Does anyone know why?

The div is floated, the element above is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inline elements simply don't take vertical margins or height into account. Block elements do.

**Edit:**

In response to comments, it looks like there are two issues at play here.

1. You have two elements with `id='generals'`. Change this to `class='generals'`.
2. Add `overflow: hidden` to your `generals` style. All of the elements inside it are floated, and so don't apply to the height of the element. Adding `overflow: hidden` changes how the element is displayed, clearing all the floats inside it.

Comment: I've tryed setting the div to block (wich it should be to start with i suppose)

dev.resihop.nu is the adress, I would love to hear your thoughts!

Comment: It's the `p` that has to be block in order for it to maintain some height/vertical margin. What element at the given URL am I looking at?

Comment: the "p" is a block(however on that page, there is no blocklevel p element)

The poorly behaving element is div.generals, I want it to look like http://dev.resihop.nu/search?from=&to=&when=&got_car=1

Comment: didn't work, also I need the overflow to be visible, because I use it for error messages, for example http://dev.resihop.nu/search?from=&to=&when=&got_car=1